# Range Operators (..< and ...) on Swift Strings

Tags: ios, swift

Can someone explain why half open and closed ranges no longer work the same on strings in Swift 3?

This code works:

```
var hello = "hello"
let start = hello.index(hello.startIndex, offsetBy: 1)
let end = hello.index(hello.startIndex, offsetBy: 4)
let range = start..<end   // <-- Half Open Range Operator still works
let ell = hello.substring(with: range)
```

But this does not:

```
var hello = "hello"
let start = hello.index(hello.startIndex, offsetBy: 1)
let end = hello.index(hello.startIndex, offsetBy: 4)
let range = start...end   // <-- Closed Range Operator does NOT work
let ello = hello.substring(with: range)   // ERROR
```

It results in an error like the following:

```
Cannot convert value of type 'ClosedRange<String.Index>' (aka 'ClosedRange<String.CharacterView.Index>') to expected argument type 'Range<String.Index>' (aka 'Range<String.CharacterView.Index>')
```

Answer (score 2):

To do what you're trying to do, don't call `substring(with:)`. Just subscript directly:

```
var hello = "hello"
let start = hello.index(hello.startIndex, offsetBy: 1)
let end = hello.index(hello.startIndex, offsetBy: 4)
let ello = hello[start...end] // "ello"
```

Answer (score 0):

- Why `let range = start..<end` work?

`NSRange` is what you need if you wanna use `substring(with:)` ([described here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsstring/1418469-substring)).

Here is [the definition](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/range) of `Range`:

> A half-open interval over a comparable type, from a lower bound up to,
>   but not including, an upper bound.

To create a `Range`:

> You create Range instances by using the half-open range operator
>   (..<).

So bellow code is exactly true (and its will work):

```
var hello = "hello"
let start = hello.index(hello.startIndex, offsetBy: 1)
let end = hello.index(hello.startIndex, offsetBy: 4)
let range = start..<end   // <-- Half Open Range Operator still works
let ell = hello.substring(with: range)
```

- Why `let range = start...end` not works:

With bellow you forced a `ClosedRange` to become an `Range`:

```
var hello = "hello"
let start = hello.index(hello.startIndex, offsetBy: 1)
let end = hello.index(hello.startIndex, offsetBy: 4)
let range = start...end   // <-- Closed Range Operator does NOT work
let ello = hello.substring(with: range)   // ERROR
```

- How to convert `ClosedRange` to `Range` ?

[Converting between half-open and closed ranges](https://oleb.net/blog/2016/09/swift-3-ranges/)